# Mysql SELECT query return double values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with a SELECT query, which instead of returning me a single value, gives me too many. 
The query below:

```
            SELECT costi.id, costo, descrizione, categoria
            FROM costi 
            INNER JOIN categorie 
            WHERE costi.id = 140
```

The query fishes data from a DB with two tables (costi and categorie)
[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znuht.jpg)

The problem I'm having is that: 
If, for example, I run the query on PHP my admin (by entering instead of $ _POST ['id'], the ID of a cost like 140) instead of just going back one row with the associated data, It comes back two rows (one for each category I've created).
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD91a.png)

They are identical rows, with the same values, except for the category field that is different.
I need back just one row with the correct data.

Comment: You're not specifying any condition for the join. In other words, you're missing an `on` statement following the join.

Comment: Please specify some conditions to join. Otherwise it will populate like now only

Comment: If you don't specifying a ON statement your INNER JOIN will work as a CROSS JOIN instead makes sense that you get duplicated records. No body explained why it happens so i will explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it should be:

```sql
SELECT costi.id, costo, descrizione, categoria
FROM costi 
INNER JOIN categorie
    ON costi.id = categorie.id --note the join condition
WHERE costi.id = 140
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your query result  ..

You could use a group_concat for get the result in one row

```
   SELECT  costo, descrizione, group_concat(categoria)
        FROM costi 
        INNER JOIN categorie 
        WHERE costi.id = 140
 group by   costo, descrizione
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN the 2 tables using the foreign key in the JOIN statement

```
SELECT costi.id, costo, descrizione, categoria
FROM costi 
    INNER JOIN categorie ON categorie.id = costi.idcatagoria
WHERE costi.id = 140
```

Now the query knows which rows in the 2 tables are related to each other

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 approaches:

1. Use the following query avoiding `INNER JOIN`:

   ```
       SELECT h.id, h.costo, h.descrizione, i.categoria
       FROM costi h, categorie i 
       WHERE h.id = 140 and h.idcategoria=i.id
   ```
2. You can use `GROUP BY` with `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Why did you remove the JOIN in preference for an AND? 2 steps back surley

Comment: They are basically the same thing. Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins

Comment: But why change the OP's code for what you believe is no benefit

Comment: Because of the personal preferences. I was just suggesting a working alternative. Using inner join or where is completely his choice.

Answer (score 0):

use the following query avoiding INNER JOIN:

```
 SELECT h.id, h.costo, h.descrizione, i.categoria
    FROM costi h, categorie i 
    WHERE h.id = 140 and h.idcategoria=i.id
```

Comment: old way to join..this method could be deprecated in the future

Answer (score -1):

specifying any condition for the join. 
like table.id on ...

specify condition then you will get limited results